# 'Order By ' SQL issue (out of range date/time value)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I'm having an issue with the below query:

```
SELECT 
    Consignments.LegacyID, 
    Consignments.TripDate,
    Consignments.CollectionName, 
    CASE 
        WHEN Sage2.InvoiceSummaryType = 'HT' THEN DeliveryTown 
        ELSE DeliveryName + ', ' + DeliveryTown + ', ' + DeliveryPostCode END AS 'DeliveryName', 
    Consignments.Pallets, 
    Consignments.Weight, 
    Consignments.BaseRate, 
    Consignments.FuelSurcharge, 
    Consignments.AdditionalCharges, 
    Consignments.BaseRate * Consignments.Quantity AS 'InvoiceValue', 
    Consignments.InvoiceNumber, 
    Consignments.Customer 
FROM 
    Consignments 

    INNER JOIN SageAccount 
        ON Consignments.Customer = SageAccount.LegacyID 
        AND SageAccount.Customer = 'true' 

    LEFT OUTER JOIN SageAccount AS Sage2 
        ON SageAccount.InvoiceAccount = Sage2.LegacyID 
WHERE 
    (Sage2.Customer = 'true') 
    AND (Consignments.Customer = @Customer) 
    AND (Consignments.InvoiceNumber IS NOT NULL) 
    OR (Sage2.Customer = 'true') 
    AND (Consignments.InvoiceNumber IS NOT NULL) 
    AND (Sage2.InvoiceAccount = @Customer)  

ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN Sage2.InvoiceSummaryType = 'HR' THEN TripDate  
        WHEN Sage2.InvoiceSummaryType = 'HS' THEN Consignments.LegacyID 
    END
```

For some reason, it keeps giving me the following error:

`The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value order by`

But only when it tries to `Order By TripDate`, i.e. when the case 'HR' happens. TripDate is a 'datetime field'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having just read the question again I can't explain the specific symptons you are getting without seeing the execution plan (I would have expected `HS` to cause the problem). Generally though you should avoid mixing datatypes in `CASE` expressions as below as it simply doesn't work `select case when 1=0 then GETDATE() else 'foo' end` will fail as it tries to convert the string to `datetime`

```
ORDER BY
         CASE
                  WHEN Sage2.InvoiceSummaryType = 'HR'
                  THEN TripDate
                  WHEN Sage2.InvoiceSummaryType = 'HS'
                  THEN Consignments.LegacyID
         END
```

To get around this you can use `cast(TripDate as float)` - assuming (perhaps incorrectly) that the ID field is numeric or use this idiom.

```
ORDER BY
         CASE
                  WHEN Sage2.InvoiceSummaryType = 'HR'
                  THEN TripDate
                  ELSE NULL
         END,
         CASE
                  WHEN Sage2.InvoiceSummaryType = 'HS'
                  THEN Consignments.LegacyID
                  ELSE NULL
         END
```

You would need to check the execution plans for performance comparisons.

Comment: I guess your suspicion is correct, in a way. There might be no problems until the set contains both kinds of data. After that, you might say either that both of them cause the problem, or say that neither of them causes the problem, it is just using them together that results in an error. Indeed, avoid mixing data types or coerce them into some common type before using them in comparisons, as you have said. +1

Comment: Thanks buddy, I tried your second query and it worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need an "END" after your THEN TripDate ?

Answer (score 0):

All the options in the CASE statement have to be the same datatype.  Is LegacyID a char?

You'd have this problem anywhere, not just in an order by.  If you do CASE WHEN 'x' THEN (some int) WHEN 'y' THEN (some date) and SQL cannot do an implicit conversion of all values, then you're toast.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a cased ordering, then the data types have to be compatible with each other.

try this for the date:

```
Convert(int, TripDate , 112)
```

A format of 112 will give you yyyymmdd, which is useful in ordering by date as an integer. Use 1 - [date] for descending.

This is assuming that the LegacyID is an integer. Otherwise, you can try casting the date to a type SQL_VARIANT

Comment: Any idea how `SQL_VARIANT` sorts? Does it do a binary sort? If so that might not be suitable.

Comment: I'm not sure off the top of my head. You can always convert to an integer as above, then case to a sql_variant. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx